# Компиляция, зависящая от наличия include

Tags: c++, gcc

Задача следующая:

Есть множество header-файлов (назовём их `File_N.h`, где `N` от 1 до 100) с соответствующими им `File_N.cpp`. Они не относятся к конкретному проекту, но могут понадобиться в любой момент. Нужен какой-то механизм, который бы при наличии всего лишь одного `#include <File_1.h>` в каком-то из исходных файлов, автоматически добавлял в проект `File_1.cpp`. Или не автоматически, а с минимальной ручной работой.

Текущая реализация - это отсутствие `.cpp` файлов, а весь код полностью содержится в header'ах, но из-за этого сильно страдает скорость компиляции, также есть некоторые другие проблемы (например, инициализация статических переменных класса).

Читал про расширения компилятора `#pragma interface/implementation` [(подробности)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Interface.html), но не придумал, как их приспособить. Есть ощущение, что модули из будущего стандарта могли бы мне помочь, но их пока нет в `gcc` даже экспериментально.

Компилятор gcc, среда разработки CLion (сборка с помощью CMake).

Comment: А тип итогового проекта какой (приложение/библиотека)?

Comment: А в чем проблема все .cpp сразу использовать?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, если речь о библиотеке, то будет распухать файл.

Comment: Все .cpp использовать бессмысленно, так как не нужны, и к тому же очень долгая компиляция. Тип итогового проекта - shared library, но это не важно, так как используется не по прямому назначению. После компиляции должен быть единый файл.

Comment: обычно определеют переменную для cmake и на основании ее значения решают, что включать в проект. Если зависимости сильно сложнее - никто не мешает написать скрипт, который будет генерировать правильный cmake файл.

Comment: Действительно, может проще подключить все `*.cpp`, а для оптимизации размера бинарника можно использовать LTO

Comment: Посмотрите еще на  варианты с pch (precompiled headers). Они позволят подключить все хэдэры и сократить время компиляции

Answer (score 3):

Соберите статическую библиотеку (*.a) из всех File_*.cpp.
В конечный исполняемый файл попадут только те единицы трансляции, символы из которых используются.

Comment: Есть еще нюанс: все эти файлы и файлы проекта используют один общий header со статическими методами, статическими внеклассовыми переменными с определенным приоритетом инициализации и набор макросов для работы со всей этой статикой. Думаю, что предварительная компиляция отдельных частей не поможет

Comment: Так или иначе, либо придется пере собирать все файлы, после изменения глобального *.h, либо править список используемых *.cpp вручную.